# NFC-V SLIX-S write password

Tags: android, passwords, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I'm trying to set AFI password to the SLIX-S tag. I found the command for set password is B3: take a look please ([Link here: Page 12](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SL2S5302_SL2S5402.pdf)). But every time my set password command crash. I think  the format of the code line I use is wrong. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot for anything can help me.

**Update:**

I tried this one sequence of bytes but still can't set password successfully.

```
buffer = nfcv.transceive(new byte[] { 
       0x00, //flag 
       0xB3, //set password command
       0x04, //manufacturer code (NXP should be 0x04)
       0xe0, 0x04, 0x02, 0x50, 0x04, 0xfa, 0xab, 0x4c, //UID
       0x10, //password identifier for AFI
       0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x38, //XOR-password from password: 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34 
                               //with xor(0x09) and xor(0x05)
       0x11, 0xba }); // CRC16 from XOR-password
```

Comment: This issue should be fixed by answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723703/nfc-v-icode-slix-sl2s2002/55168046#55168046

Comment: Did you try the flag value of 22? Regards,
Gambrius

Answer (score 1):

0xA6 is the command to turn on the password protection for AFI.

From the data sheet I understand (have not tried myself) that you need to set the password first with "Write Password" 0xB4. Then you need to transmit this password with "Set Password" 0xB3 in order to execute password protected commands like "Password Protect EAS/AFI" 0xA6.

Comment: Thank you for advice but I still can't find correct format for set password. I updated my question with new code. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Have you tried to send the command "Write Password" 0xB4 before you use the "Set Password" 0xB3 command?  BTW: don't include the crc in the data of the transceive method. The crc is calculated by the transceive method. See the documentation _"Applications must not append the CRC to the payload, it will be automatically calculated."_ [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcV.html#transceive(byte[]))

Comment: yes I tried also use B4 and also B3 command without CRC data. The result is unfortunately still the same.